# material ui styling not applying

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styles

For some reason my material ui styles are not applying to my html element? Any idea why? I have no other styles applied to this page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoginForm from '../components/form/loginForm';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const classes = makeStyles( (theme) => ({
  root: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(8),
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
}) )

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className = {classes.root}>
        <LoginForm/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Login;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, if you want to style your class component, you should use `withStyles`.
 Try this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoginForm from '../components/form/loginForm';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(8),
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
})

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
    return(
      <div className = {classes.root}>
        <LoginForm/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withStyles(useStyles)(Login);
```

Comment: how would I structure that withstyles call if i am already using the react-redux connect function on the class?

Comment: @Tamjid You can use ```export default connect(mapStateToProps)((withStyles(useStyles)(Login)))```

Answer (score 2):

`makeStyles` returns a react hook to use in the component. Hooks also only work in functional components, so you'll need to convert `Login` to a functional component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoginForm from '../components/form/loginForm';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(8),
    backgroundColor: "lightblue"
  }
}));

const Login = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return(
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <LoginForm/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Login;
```

[image: Edit makeStyles hook creator]

Comment: when I try that I get the following error when trying to initialise the const classes: parsing error unexpected token

Comment: @Tamjid Sorry about that, I hadn't noticed that you were trying to use `makeStyles` with a class-based component. Since it returns a react hook it makes compatible only with functional components. I updated my answer and added a codesandbox.